# Is this derivation of the relation between the momentum and energy of a photon correct?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, kinematics, momentum, speed-of-light

$$E=\int Pdt$$ where P is power
$$E=\int F⋅vdt$$
$$E=\int\frac{dp}{dt}\cdot vdt$$
$$E=\int vdp$$
Since the velocity and momentum are in the same direction, the dot product is equal to the product of the magnitudes.
For a photon v=c,
$$E=\int cdp$$
$$E=c\int dp$$
$$E=pc$$
For some context, I am a high school student. I got this while messing around with equations. I haven't really seen a proof like this online so I was wondering if it was correct

Comment: The problem with this derivation is that there can't be a "force" acting on the photon, so $\frac{dp}{dt} = 0$.  We can't just define the power $P$ with this term at the start of the derivation, since Newton's equation doesn't apply to the photon.  The relation $E = p c$ comes straight from special relativity, or from Maxwell's equations for a "flash of light".

Comment: @Charm
Why can't I define F as $\frac{dp}{dt}$? Since $p=\frac{h}{\lambda}$, can't we say $\frac{dp}{dt}=-\frac{h}{(\lambda)^2}\frac{d(\lambda)}{dt}$? During refraction, $\lambda$ changes.

Comment: During refraction, $v$ isn't equal to $c$, so the last step of your derivation doesn't work.  Newton's equation doesn't apply to the photon (a massless particle), which always travels at $c$ in vacuum.  It would be strange to be able to derive the relativistic relation $E = p c$ while using classical non-relativistic physics (i.e Newton's theory).

Comment: @Charm I get that v isn't equal to c during refraction and since I don't know much about refraction and its relation with time, I can't derive an expression for it but the step would work for the case where light is in a vacuum since the wavelength of a photon does change if it experiences a gravitational redshift/blueshift and the speed is constant

Comment: Gravity doesn't apply neither on the photon, in Newton's theory, since the photon mass is zero.  You just have to accept that the relation $E = p c$ *cannot* be derived using classical newtonian physics only.  It is a *relativistic relation*!  Any attempt to derive it with Newton's theory fails when you consider carefully all of the steps.  But I want to add that your *question* is still a good one, since it is perfectly legit to ask *why* classical "proofs" fail.  What's wrong with Newtonian theory when we want to derive $E = p c$?